# removeAll() method is taking long time

Tags: java, list

```
List<Batch> vAllBatchList = getAllBatchCollection().toList(); //Has 700k records
List<Batch> vKeepableBatchCollection = getKeepableBatchCollection(pDaysKeepHistory).toList(); //has 600k records
vAllBatchList.removeAll(vKeepableBatchCollection);
```

In the above 3rd line removeAll method is taking too much time to finish. How to optimize the removeAll method here?

Comment: Could you use sets instead of lists?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you convert the `List` of element to remove to a `Set`, it should be faster:

```
vAllBatchList.removeAll(new HashSet<>(vKeepableBatchCollection));
```

This is assuming `Batch` class overrides `hashCode` and `equals` properly.

Explanation: `removeAll` for `ArrayList` (I'm assuming your `vAllBatchList` `List` is an `ArrayList`) iterates over all the elements of the `List` on which it is called, and checks if the passed `Collection` contains them. If the passed `Collection` is a `Set`, `contains` will take expected constant time (`O(1)`), while if the `Collection` is a `List`, it will take linear time (`O(n)`).

Of course, if you can directly generate a `Set` of the elements of `vKeepableBatchCollection` instead of first creating a `List` and then converting it to a `Set`, it would be even better.

Comment: Nice answer, If what you said in your answer exist in reality, Why not java architect use this trick directly in `removeAll`?

Comment: @YCF_L I can't say what the reasoning of the Java architects was, but it's possible that such an optimization will not improve performance in all possible scenarios.